# The installation of python from the python.org is being done in the Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe folder. How execute on default folder?

Tags: python, windows, installation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZlwQ.png
any ideas for solving the correct destination of python installation and execution?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJZhK.jpg

Comment: When your run the install it should ask you where you want it installed and show a default. Change that. Perhaps using the Microsoft store makes that not happen. In that case go to python.org and manually download the windows installer `.exe` file and run that.

Comment: i'm putting default. I don't know what happening. I did just that, but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you changing the default to a the absolute path of specific folder, such as `C:\python3`? That's how I do it and it works for me (using the installer I manually downloaded from https://www.python.org/). Note: If you already have it installed in the undesired location, you may have to un-install that first.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just did install another version of python.I was installing python on version 3.8 and was going to the microsoft / windowsa pps folder even though I was selecting the default install location. so I just installed a previous version and now it worked.

Comment: Could be an issue with the Windows installer for version 3.8.0, which was released just a couple of weeks ago (October 14th). That said, I was able to use it to upgrade the Python 3.7.x that was already installed in the `C:\python3` directory on my system.

Comment: The standard installation from python.org has nothing to do with "python.exe" in "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps". The latter is shipped with Windows as a convenience for opening the Microsoft Store to install the app distribution of Python. It seems that you simply forgot to set up the environment variables (`PATH` and `PATHEXT`) in the installer. There's an option for this, but it's disabled by default. Go into the control panel programs and modify your current installation to select this option.